# Javascript Sub-Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I recently ran into the problem where I would like to select multiple elements from an array, to return a sub-array. For example, given the array:

```
a = [1, 5, 1, 6, 2, 3, 7, 8, 3]
```

And the index array of:

```
i = [3, 5, 6]
```

I want to select all elements in a, who's index appears in i. So the output in my simple example would be:

```
[6, 3, 7]
```

I completely realise I could use a for loop over i and construct a new array then use Array.push(a[index (in i)]) to add in each, but I was wondering if there was a clearer/cleaner way to achieve this (possibly using underscore.js, or something similar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
i.map(function(x) { return a[x]; })
// => [6, 3, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
a = [1, 5, 1, 6, 2, 3, 7, 8, 3];
i = [3,5,6];
var res= [];     //for show result array
for (var n in a){      //loop a[]
 for(var index in i){     //loop i[]
     if(  n == i[index] )     //n is index of a[]
     res.push(a[n]);          //add array if equal n index and i[] value
 }
 }
 alert(res);    // 6,3,7
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map` function to achieve your desired result.

```
var a = [1, 5, 1, 6, 2, 3, 7, 8, 3];

var i = [3, 5, 6];

var mapped = i.map(function(index) { 
    return a[index]; 
});

console.log(mapped);
```

Here is the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d816hme7/).

However with above example, `map` not be available in all browsers yet. Here is the quote from documentation of `map`.

> map was added to the `ECMA-262` standard in the 5th edition; as such it
>   may not be present in all implementations of the standard.

If your code will be running in old browsers then you will need to add a `polyfill`. However there are libraries that give you similar functionality with `polyfills` for older browsers. Along with `map` function, [underscodejs](http://underscorejs.org/) has tons of other helpful functions. I higly recommend you to look at what `underscorejs` has to offer. It provides tons of helper functions and has quite wide range browser support.

You would do following in `underscorejs` and wont have to worry if your code works in cross browsers.

```
var a = [1, 5, 1, 6, 2, 3, 7, 8, 3];

var mapped = _.map([3, 5, 6], function(index) {
    return a[index];
});

alert(mapped);
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e03h1sf8/1/) for that.

Comment: Thanks Subash, That is exactly what I was looking for. I was actually originally trying to do this with underscore. But I didn't think of a way to do it initially! Thanks again for your help :) It is much appreciated!